# Linking pdf file from directory in html

Tags: python, django, pdf, linker, blank-line

I am having trouble creating a link to a pdf document in my directory using python/django. The link in the html page looks like this:

```
<a href="pilots/12-and-Holding.pdf" target="_blank" Read Me</a>
```

It's a pdf I want to open up on another page and be available for download. The fold it sets in is pilots/12-and-Holding.pdf.

Where am I going wrong? The error I'm getting is:

```
 Using the URLconf defined in scripts.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

 The current path, pilots/12-and-Holding.pdf, didn't match any of these.
```

Does this require a url path?

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: every URL in your HTML need code in `urls.py` to recognize this URL and run code which send this file. Only files in folder `/static/` may not need it.

Comment: @furas that worked thank you!

Answer (score 2):

@furas has already explained it.

i'll assume that you have a folder `pilots` under `static` folder which holds your file `12-and-Holding.pdf`

then in your template all you need is:

```
<a href="{% static 'pilots/12-and-Holding.pdf' %}" target="_blank">Read Me</a>
```

make sure you have `{% load static %}` at the very top of your template.